# How do you use __declspec(align(16)) with a template?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, alignment

I'm trying to make my `class 16-byte` aligned with `__declspec(align(16))`; however it is a template class.

If I place `__declspec(align(16))` before the template keyword, it tells me that variable attributes are not allowed there.

If I place it before the class keyword, the whole class becomes invalid and all methods show errors.

So how is it done then?

Comment: What about pasting the error messages and/or a minimal example?

Comment: This might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388934/aligning-member-variables-by-template-type or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750832/c-parent-class-alignment

Answer (score 1):

This implementation probably answers this request:

```
template <class T, std::size_t Align>
struct alignas(Align) aligned_storage
{
    T a;
    T b;
};

template <class T, std::size_t Align>
struct aligned_storage_members
{
    alignas(Align) T a;
    alignas(Align) T b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    aligned_storage<uint32_t, 8> as;
    std::cout << &as.a << " " << &as.b << std::endl;

    aligned_storage_members<uint32_t, 8> am;
    std::cout << &am.a << " " << &am.b << std::endl;
}

// Output: 
0x73d4b7aa0b20 0x73d4b7aa0b24
0x73d4b7aa0b30 0x73d4b7aa0b38
```

The first struct (which can be defined as a class of course), is **8-byte aligned**, whereas the second struct is not aligned by itself, but rather **each of the members is 8-byte aligned**.